# Converting between strings and intergers. Python

Tags: python, string, raspberry-pi, int

I am building a barcode scanner. The scanner works as expected. I then decided to change the value by an offset of ascii 5 for extra data protection. This also worked as expected. For further security I wish to add a password that the user inputs. My original code before the password addition is as follows....

```
barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("ascii")

barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) +5) for c in barcodeData
```

I then decided to add the user input in the top line

```
userkey = input()
key=float(userkey)
```

then replaced

```
barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) +5) for c in barcodeData
```

with

```
barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) +'key') for c in barcodeData
```

this throws the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand types(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I wish to have the system run at all inputs yet only show the correct output when the user inputs the number `5`

thanks in advance

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, default="barcodes.csv",
    help="path to output CSV file containing barcodes")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

#start video stream and allow warming of camera
print("While camera is warming up, please enter the numerical password.")
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
userkey=input()
key=str(userkey)


# open the output CSV file for writing and initialize the set of
# QR barcodes found thus far
csv = open(args["output"], "w")
found = set()

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it to
    # have a maximum width of 600 pixels
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)

    # find the QR Codes in the frame and decode each of the barcodes
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)

    # loop over the detected barcodes
    for barcode in barcodes:
        # extract the bounding box location of the barcode and draw
        # the bounding box surrounding the barcode on the image
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)


        # the barcode data is a bytes object so if we want to draw it
        # on our output image we need to convert it to a string first
        barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("ascii")


        #Chnage the decoded ascii string by a value of 5 charcters
        barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) + 'key') for c in barcodeData)

        # draw the barcode data and barcode type on the image
        text = "{}".format(barcodeData)
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # if the barcode text is currently not in our CSV file, write
        # the timestamp + barcode to disk and update the set
        if barcodeData not in found:
            csv.write("{},{}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now(),
                barcodeData))
            csv.flush()
            found.add(barcodeData)

    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("QR Code Secret Message Scanner", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# close the output CSV file nad perform cleanup
csv.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Comment: `ord` returns `int` number and you trying to concat it with string, to fix it just wrap with `str` like this `str(ord(c))`, or provide an example of input and output to help you

Comment: iv added my full code in the original post if this is of use, my plan is to have the code run for all inputs of an interger number - error -     barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) + 'key') for c in barcodeData)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Try to convert the number value to string if you just want to concatenate a string.
Or try to convert the string value to a number if you want to sum up the value. That's is the only issue you've got.

Comment: Try this barcodeData = "".join(str(chr(ord(c)) + 'key') for c in barcodeData)

Comment: @kwingkwingko, so this reads the code, however it reads the barcode as is and doesnt chnage the ascii value by the input - furthermore - each character is folowed by "key"

Comment: @kwingkwingko `chr(ord(c))` what's the sense of it? it's same that just simply do `c + 'key'` but in your suggestion it's two unuseful operations

Comment: @Jack just do next `chr(ord(c) + key)` and that's all

Comment: hi @alex2007v thanks for your suggestion. This results in error     barcodeData = "".join(str(chr(ord(c)) + key) for c in barcodeData)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str ----- after removing the str(joi.....) the code returns multiple question marks above my qr code

Answer (score 0):

`key` being returned here is not a string but a data type of int, if you want to convert it you will have to type cast it to a string by doing:

```
key = str(userkey)
```

and likewise a string to int would be:

```
key = int(userkey)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @FishingCode. I still get the same error mixed with invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'userkey'

Comment: Did you mean int(userkey)?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line (problem in your line that ord return int and key has single quotes, which I assume a bug)

```
barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) + 'key') for c in barcodeData)
```

to next:

```
barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) + key) for c in barcodeData)
```

An example:

```
key = 5 # your offset
barcode = 'AB1234VD'
barcode = "".join(chr(ord(c) + key) for c in barcode)
print(barcode) # 'FG6789[I'
```

P.S. don't forget convert `key` in your code to `int`